# Is it possible with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, typo3

I currently have a lot to do with Typo3 (10.3) and am generally quite good at it.
But there is a challenge that makes me despair.

Maybe it is simple for one or the other but I think I'm on the tube.
It is roughly about having an intranet exposed to the outside world. (an LDAP query will come later)

I have the following URL internally (intranet.unternehmen.de).

Now everything works fine on the internal side, and there is a reverse proxy entry to the outside
app.unternehemen.de/intranet delivers this page.

The problem now is that the page is displayed, but all references / images / CSS are not there because the folder / intranet / is still missing in the URL. (If this folder is manually attached to a URL of an image or PDF, it works wonderfully.

There must be a way to add this folder as soon as the host e.g. app.unternehmen.de is?

I have already made various attempts to solve this using .htaccess, but these rules are not satisfactory.

e.g.

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} "^ app.unternehmen.de $" [NC, OR]
RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} "^ app.unternehmen.de $" [NC] RewriteRule "^ / intranet /(.*)$" "http://app.unternehmen.de/intranet/" [R = 301, L]
```

or in TypoScript (if someone has an idea)

```
[globalString = IENV: HTTP_HOST = app.unternehmen.de]
cURL = app.unternehmen.de/intranet/
[END]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay there is an solution.

In Version 10 there are new selectors. 
Following snipped works.

```
[!ip("192.168.*")]
config {
    absRefPrefix = /intranet/
}
[END]
```